# what does mean 0.0.0.0:22 under the column local address of netstat command?

Tags: output, netstat

I read that 0.0.0.0:22 means that access to port 22 is allowed from any ip addresses (any other computers). However, the column "local address" of netstat only refers to ip of local addresses (local computers), but not refer to ip address outside the local network. I am confused here.

What does 0.0.0.0:22 means? if I have a computer with IP 165.80.02.66, can someone with IP 128.60.22.10 connect to my computer on port 22 based on 0.0.0.0:22.

Comment: Both IPs you've provided are not local addresses, so the answer is likely no. A local address usually looks something like 10.0.0.x or 192.168.x.x. You can check if ports are open to the public with [Shieldsup](https://www.grc.com/shieldsup).

Comment: if 0.0.0.0:22 refers only to ip addresses within my local network, why I can connect to a server from my home computer which has IP address outside the local network of the server.

Comment: It is not uncommon to enable connections from bother the local network and the internet. We don't know how things are set up on your PC.